# dns - BIND - how to return a different IP based on request's subnet

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

We have an intranet DNS server (system-config-bind on RHEL)  serving office A, and a VPN connecting offices A and B.  Office A has a server named "dev".

In office A, to access a server "dev" on the local network,  the address is 192.168.**1**.13

In office B, to access a server "dev" over the VPN, the address is 192.168.**2**.13

My question is this - can I set the DNS server to return  a different IP for "dev" based on the subnet of the incoming request?

Example:
In office A, BIND returns 192.168.**1**.13 as the "dev" IP, because the originating request is from the 192.168.**1**/24 subnet.

In office B, BIND returns 192.168.**2**.13 as the "dev" IP, because the originating request is from the 192.168.**2**/24 subnet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use views:

```
view "officeA" {
   match-clients { 192.168.1.0/24; };

   include "/etc/named.conf.zones-rfc1912";
   include "/etc/named.conf.zones-common";
   include "/etc/named.conf.zones-officeA";
};

view "officeB" {
   match-clients { 192.168.2.0/24; };

   include "/etc/named.conf.zones-rfc1912";
   include "/etc/named.conf.zones-common";
   include "/etc/named.conf.zones-officeB";
};
```