# BIND different forwarder based on response ip (rpz-ip)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, rpz

I have a recursive BIND dns server .

```
    forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
    };
```

Is it possible to change the forwarder based on **respone ip** ?

For example if the response is 192.168.1.1 then forward/redirect it to other forwarder ?

```
       //if response ip or rpz-ip = 192.168.1.1 then
        forwarders {
        8.8.4.4;
        };
```

I have found solutions like [Redirecting queries for a zone to a different nameserver](https://www.reddit.com/r/dns/comments/4rguxi/bind_redirecting_queries_for_a_zone_to_a/) **but they are based on domain name** but my question is based on RESPONSE ip .

Also found [how to return a different IP based on request's subnet](https://serverfault.com/questions/332440/dns-bind-how-to-return-a-different-ip-based-on-requests-subnet) which is based on request ip.

The response ip could be detected by http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/rpz.html#policy-triggers but i could not find a way to forward it to another forwarder .

Comment: have you seen haproxy. Maybe it can help. www.haproxy.org/

Comment: I prefer using BIND alone if possible .

Comment: Didn't you get an answer to this on the `bind-users` mailing list?

Comment: Unfortunately no . https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2017-September/099090.html